# First Element of vector with weird data

Tags: c++, vector

I will try to explain the best I can the problem:

I have a class Polinomio (Polynomial in spanish). that has a vector of the class Monomio (Monomial).

In Polinomio I have this method:

```
void Polinomio::rellenarRandom() {
    Monomio mon;
    vector<Monomio> vec (getGrado() + 1, mon);

    for (int i = 0; i <= getGrado(); i++) {
        int random = MIN + (rand() % (int)(MAX - MIN + 1));
        Monomio mon (random, i);
        vec[i] = mon;
    }
    cout << vec[0] << endl;
    cout << vec[1] << endl;
    cout << vec[2] << endl;
    cout << vec[3] << endl;
    cout << vec[4] << endl;
    setMonomio(vec);
}
```

It fills with random Monomials the vector vec, then it sets the vetor "Monomio" (bad named, I know) to this random vector.

The cout's make this output (it varies, but an example):

- -11x^0
- -69x^1
- 28x^2
- -78x^3
- -53x^4

The setter is pretty simple:

```
void Polinomio::setMonomio(vector<Monomio> vec) {
    this->monomios = vec;
}
```

And in the main I have:

```
Polinomio pol (5); // Creates a Polinomial with grade 5
pol.rellenarRandom();
cout << "pol: " << pol << endl;
```

That cout makes this output:

> pol: 3473744x^0 + -69x^1 + 28x^2 + -78x^3 + -53x^4 + -9x^5 +

I tested many times, to try to detect the mistake, but it appears to follow no pattern. The first number is different every time, but never the one it should be.

It's not a problem of the overload of << on the Polinomo class, since I also tested another access to that element, and it shows it "correctly" (the same, even if it's not what it should).

The problem must be on the setter, but I ust can't figure out what the problem is.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: (modified the setter name that was wrong to setMonomio

I added one more test, and it's driving me CRAZY. This is what I did:

1. I modified this cout before the set, to see the member that gives me problems:

   cout << "VEC :";
   cout << vec[0] << endl;

   setMonomios(vec);
2. In setMonomios, I modified setMonomios:

   void Polinomio::setMonomios(vector vec) {
       cout << "set: " << vec[0] << endl;
       this->monomios = vec;
       cout << "postset: " << this->monomios[0] << endl;
   }

result:

- VEC :0x^0
- set: 3670352x^0
- postset: 3670352x^0

So, the valor get's modified somehow when I call the setter?

ANSWERS (EDIT's you have asked for):

**Tony Jiang:**

Did that, the result was (only with the first element, that gives problems):
* VEC :0x^0
* set: 3670352x^0
* postset: 3670352x^0

**Wolfgang.Finkbeiner:**

The << operator overload:

```
inline ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const Polinomio &a) {
    auto v = a.getMonomios();
    for (vector<Monomio>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        o << *it << " + ";
    return o;
}
```

**DOUGLAS O. MOEN**

getGrado does always return the same value. The reason I don't use vector.size () is because in some other functions I use it before initializing the vector, or while modifying it, so it can have unexpected results if I do. Anyway, it's tested, it doesn't give any problem.

**PaulMcKenzie**

I don't know what you mean exactly by the copy semantics, but anyway, I'll post it:

```
#include "Monomio.h"

Monomio::Monomio() {
    coeficiente = 0;
    exponente = 0;
}

Monomio::Monomio(int coef) {
    coeficiente = coef;
    exponente = 0;
}

Monomio::Monomio(int coef, int exp) {
    coeficiente = coef;
    exponente = exp;
}

Monomio::Monomio(const Monomio& orig) {
}

Monomio::~Monomio() {
}



//Getters & Setters:
int Monomio::getCoeficiente() const {
    return coeficiente;
}

int Monomio::getExponente() const {
    return exponente;
}

void Monomio::setCoeficiente(int c) {
    this->coeficiente = c;
}

void Monomio::setExponente(int e) {
    this->exponente = e;
}
```

**R Sahu**

The MCVE (maybe not exactly Minimal, but it's a small project):

Apart from the class Monomio (posted above) to reproduce you might need:

The class Polinomio:

```
#include "Polinomio.h"

Polinomio::Polinomio() {
    setGrado(0);
    setMonomios(vector<Monomio> (0));
    srand (time(NULL));
}

Polinomio::Polinomio(const Polinomio& orig) {
    setGrado(orig.getGrado());
    setMonomios(orig.getMonomios());
    srand (time(NULL));
}

Polinomio::Polinomio(int grado) {
    setGrado(grado);
    cout << "grado:" << getGrado() << endl;
    Monomio mon;
    setMonomios(vector<Monomio> (getGrado() + 1, mon));
    srand (time(NULL));
}

Polinomio::~Polinomio() {
}

int Polinomio::getGrado() const {
    return this->grado;
}

vector<Monomio> Polinomio::getMonomios() const {
    return this->monomios;
}

void Polinomio::rellenarRandom() {
    Monomio mon;
    vector<Monomio> vec (getGrado() + 1, mon);

    for (int i = 0; i <= getGrado(); i++) {
//        int random = MIN + (rand() % (int)(MAX - MIN + 1));
        int random = 1 +  i;
        Monomio mon (random, i);
        vec[i] = mon;
    }

    cout << "VEC :";
    cout << vec[0] << endl;

    setMonomios(vec);
    auto v = monomios;

    cout << "V: ";
    cout << v[0] << endl;
}

void Polinomio::rellenarRandom(int grado) {

}

void Polinomio::setGrado(int grado) {
    this->grado = grado;
}

void Polinomio::setMonomios(vector<Monomio> vec) {
    cout << "set: " << vec[0] << endl;
    this->monomios = vec;
    cout << "postset: " << this->monomios[0] << endl;
}
```

And the Header files (for the operators mainly, but in case you see anything weird please tell me):

```
#ifndef POLINOMIO_H
#define POLINOMIO_H

#include "Monomio.h"

class Polinomio {
    int grado;
public: vector<Monomio> monomios;
public:
    Polinomio();
    Polinomio (int grado);
    Polinomio(const Polinomio& orig);
    virtual ~Polinomio();
    int getGrado () const;
    void setGrado (int grado);
    void rellenarRandom ();
    void rellenarRandom (int grado);
    vector<Monomio> getMonomios () const;
    void setMonomios (vector<Monomio> vec);
private:
    const int MAX = 100;
    const int MIN = -100;
};

//Operators:

inline ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const Polinomio &a) {
    auto v = a.getMonomios();
    for (vector<Monomio>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        o << *it << " + ";
    return o;
}

inline Polinomio operator+(const Polinomio &a, const Polinomio &b) {
}

inline Polinomio operator-(const Polinomio &a, const Polinomio &b) {
}

inline Polinomio operator*(const Polinomio &a, const Polinomio &b) {
}


#endif  /* POLINOMIO_H */



#ifndef MONOMIO_H
#define MONOMIO_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Monomio {
    int coeficiente;
    int exponente;

public:
    Monomio();
    Monomio(int coef);
    Monomio(int coef, int exp);
    Monomio(const Monomio& orig);
    int getCoeficiente() const;
    int getExponente() const;
    void setExponente(int e);
    void setCoeficiente(int c);
    virtual ~Monomio();

private:

};

//Operators:

inline ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const Monomio &a) {
    o << a.getCoeficiente() << "x^" << a.getExponente();
    return o;
}

inline Monomio operator+(const Monomio &a, const Monomio &b) {
    Monomio res;

    if (a.getExponente() != b.getExponente())
        throw "Suma de monomios con exponente diferente!";
    else {
        res = Monomio (a.getCoeficiente() + b.getCoeficiente(), a.getExponente());
    }

    return res;
}

inline Monomio operator-(const Monomio &a, const Monomio &b) {
    Monomio res;

    if (a.getExponente() != b.getExponente())
        throw "Suma de monomios con exponente diferente!";
    else {
        res = Monomio (a.getCoeficiente() - b.getCoeficiente(), a.getExponente());
    }

    return res;
}

inline Monomio operator*(const Monomio &a, const Monomio &b) {
    Monomio res = Monomio (a.getCoeficiente() * b.getCoeficiente(), a.getExponente() + b.getExponente());
    return res;
}

#endif  /* MONOMIO_H */
```

Plus: the Main file I use (I also did a few tests for Monomio:

```
#include "Polinomio.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Monomio a (2, 2);
    Monomio b (3, 5);
    Monomio c (3, 2);

    cout << a << " + " << c << " = " << a + c << endl;
    cout << a << " - " << c << " = " << a - c << endl;
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << a * b << endl;

    Polinomio pol (5);
    pol.rellenarRandom();
    cout << "pol: " << pol << endl;
    cout << "primero: " << pol.getMonomios().at(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The posted code looks OK. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do a quick test where `int random = i+1` to make the code deterministic.

Comment: I know you've done testing on your overloaded cout before, is it ok if you post it so I can understand what's going on better?

Comment: It would appear that getGrado() returns an int size and default constructed mon is the initialization value for those vector members.  Does getGrado() always return the same value (because you are using it twice) and if so, why is it a function?  I would suggest the for loop use (i < vec.size()), especially if getGrado() interacts with user (a guess).

Comment: Your class `Monomio` requires correct copy semanticcs due to you storing instances in `vector`.  We don't know if your `Monomio` class adheres to this since you didn't post it.  Please post this class.

Comment: I added most of the info you asked for. Please help me, I don't usually do C++, and I don't get what can be wrong :S

Comment: Also added the "MCVE", not minimal at all, I know, sorry, but I dont think I can remove too much of it without interfering.

Comment: @Swiollvfer: You didn't even try.  Why should we try?  Besides, the MCVE is not only for our benefit, it's a key component in _you learning to program_.  Almost all of the code you posted could be removed without interfering with the bug.

Comment: I did it but it did throw some weird compilation errors, I must have erased something I shouldn't, so that's why I posted the full version, still trying to figure out the MCVE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Monomio::Monomio(const Monomio& orig) {
}
```

I don't know about you, but that function looks wrong to me.

(Yes, this is the bug)

```
this->monomios = vec;
```

This makes `monomios` equal to the "value" of `vec`, which means it makes copies of all of the `Monomio` objects.  It makes copies using the copy constructor you wrote.  The copy constructor you wrote does not assign anything at all to the `Monomio` object being constructed, so they were getting values that just happened to be in memory.  Often, by coincidence, it happened to be the value of the other vector.  And sometimes it wasn't.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the error, but yes ,it is wrong, since I don't plan to use it I was going to erase it (Netbeans generated it) EDIT: It was.. can't understand

Comment: LOL, it WAS indeed related to the error. Removed it and now it's alright. Could you please explain to me why was that interfering? I don't get it

Comment: @Swiollvfer: When you copy a vector, it has to copy the elements too.  Using your copy constructor that doesn't copy.  Note that when you tried to make an MCVE , at one point you would have tried to remove the copy constructor, at which point the bug would have gone away.  That would tell you immediately that the copy constructor is directly related to the bug.

Comment: True, but why did it assign the rest of the values correctly? In my first example you can see that the other Monomios are fine, that's why I didn't even think about this

Comment: @Swiollvfer: the compiler created a copy of your `monomios` vector in memory, and when it was done it deleted that copy.  Then it created a 4 byte object in that same location with the value 3670352.  Then it deleted that thing.  Then it created your new `monomios` vector in that same location.  Since the copy constructor didn't give them values, they just kept the values that used to be there.  (Don't do this on purpose, really crazy stuff can happen)

Comment: Well. thanks a lot, you are good. And you are right, I will give more time to the MCVE next time